# After running my logic app, it shows some error message as" "We couldn't convert to Number.\r\n "

Tags: sql, azure, iot, sensors, azure-logic-apps

I am collecting data from sensors and upload to AZURE cosmo. My logic app on AZURE keep failing and show the following message

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "We couldn't convert to Number.\r\n     inner exception: We 
  couldn't convert to Number.\r\nclientRequestId:xxxxxxx",
  "source": "sql-ea.azconn-ea.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Below are the input data from cosmo. I saw that the input data has shown "ovf" and "inf". I have tried convert the data type of that column to other data type like bigiant and numeric and resubmitted. Still did not fixed that.

```
{
  "Device": "DL084",
  "Device_Group": "DLL",
  "Time": "2019-09-04T11:45:20.0000000",
  "acc_x_avg": "ovf",
  "acc_x_stdev": "inf",
  "acc_y_avg": "3832.88",
  "acc_y_stdev": "2850.45",
  "acc_z_avg": "13304.38",
  "acc_z_stdev": "2289.86",
  "cc_volt": "3.900293",
  "cp_volt": "1.940371",
  "fp_volt": "0.718475",
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ls_volt": "4.882698",
  "millis": "1073760.00",
  "rs_rpm": "0.00",
  "smp_volt": "1.070381"
}
```

I have also tried to convert the data to string. And it will show

```
"Failed to execute query. Error: Operand type clash: numeric is 
incompatible with ntext"
```

The question is how can I eliminate this error? How can I know the error is definitely due to the "inf" and "ovf" error?

The logic app code is as below

```
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Delete_a_document": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "delete",
                            "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('iot')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('messages')}/docs/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')['id'])}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Insert_row": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Insert_row": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Device": "@{item()['device']}",
                                "Device_Group": "@{items('For_each')['devicegroup']}",
                                "Time": "@{addHours(addSeconds('1970-01-01 00:00:00', int(items('For_each')['time'])), 8)}",
                                "acc_x_avg": "@items('For_each')['acc_x_avg']",
                                "acc_x_stdev": "@items('For_each')['acc_x_stdev']",
                                "acc_y_avg": "@items('For_each')['acc_y_avg']",
                                "acc_y_stdev": "@items('For_each')['acc_y_stdev']",
                                "acc_z_avg": "@items('For_each')['acc_z_avg']",
                                "acc_z_stdev": "@items('For_each')['acc_z_stdev']",
                                "cc_volt": "@items('For_each')['cc_volt']",
                                "cp_volt": "@items('For_each')['cp_volt']",
                                "fp_volt": "@items('For_each')['fp_volt']",
                                "id": "@{guid()}",
                                "ls_volt": "@items('For_each')['ls_volt']",
                                "millis": "@items('For_each')['millis']",
                                "rs_rpm": "@items('For_each')['rs_rpm']",
                                "smp_volt": "@items('For_each')['smp_volt']"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[RCD]'))}/items"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Query_documents')?['Documents']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Query_documents": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Query_documents": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "SELECT \t\t    * \nFROM \t\t\tc \nWHERE \t\t\tc.devicegroup = 'DLL' ORDER BY c._ts"
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "x-ms-max-item-count": 1000
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('iot')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('messages')}/query"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 30
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your logic app actions details?

Comment: So in your database, you data type is  BIGINT or other numeric and you want to insert value type is string?

Comment: Originally, they are float. I have converted those data type into BIGINT and numeric but the failure is still here. So, I tried to convert them to string but show error message as:
"Failed to execute query. Error: Operand type clash: numeric is 
incompatible with ntext"